# C# Generics: What does IComparable<Nullable<T>> mean?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In the following chunk of code:

```
public struct Nullable<T> : IFormattable, IComparable, INullable,
       IComparable<Nullable<T>>
{
       // ...
}
```

I understand that this struct is implementing these interfaces but I do not get the `IComparable<Nullable<T>>` part. What it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you can compare any `Nullable<T>` with another instance of `Nullable<T>` (for the same `T`) in a strongly typed way. It will have a method like this:

```
public int CompareTo(Nullable<T> other)
```

Note that the normal [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) struct doesn't have any of these interfaces. Personally I think it would be somewhat confusing to have *another* `Nullable<T>` struct kicking around the place... I would suggest that if it's in your power to do so, you rename this struct to something else. It's also pretty strange that `T` isn't constrained using the `where T : struct` constraint...

Comment: Actually this is from C# 4.0 Essentials book and it is constrained using `where T : struct`. BTY: I cannot believe you answered in less than 50 seconds ... Jon you ARE a StackOverFlow addict :-D

Comment: @Idrees: That surprises me... because the *real* `Nullable<T>` doesn't implement those interfaces, and I'm surprised Mark mentioned them. Still, I'd have to check the rest of the context...

Comment: Don't be. It's just an illustrative example in explaining struct/class constraints. He was not discussing Framework.